# jQuery .css() not functioning in Safari

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to calculate HEIGHT of an element by jQuery and set the same value to another element. The following function works in all browsers, except in Safari, where it sets 'height:0' at first and only after resizing the browser, the correct value is set.

```
setImgHeight = function(){
    window.imgHeight = $('.releaseCDinfo img').outerHeight();
$('div.releaseText').css('height', imgHeight )
    };


setImgHeight();
$(window).resize(function(){
setImgHeight();
});
```

HTML

```
<div>

<h2>Latest<br><span>Release</span></h2>

<div class="flex releaseCDinfo">

<img src="assets/img/covers/cover-boy.jpg">

<div class="releaseText">
    <h3>Boy</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
</div>
```

Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: Why are you setting "imgHeight" as a global variable? Why not just declare it with "var" so it's scope to just your "setImgHeight" method?

Comment: What's the HTML look like?

Comment: It makes no difference. I have first set the variable as VAR, this is just a result of trying different things...

Comment: Could you post the html/js in its entirety into the question? When is the snippet you pasted run?

Comment: UPDATED. The snippet is run right before the end of HTML, id $(document).ready()

Comment: If it's working after resizing maybe it's a timing issue. Try adding a setTimeout(setImgHeight, 100);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your image is likely not fully loaded but you are trying to measure it. So use jQuery's [load method](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/) which will wait until the image is loaded before you try to measure it.

Also, because outerHeight returns a unit-less pixel number (e.g. 100, not 100px), you can use jQuery's .height() method which also accepts a unit-less pixel number rather than .css() which requires a unit.

```
var setImgHeight = function(img, text){
    var imgHeight = $(img).outerHeight();  
    $(text).height(imgHeight);  
};


$('.releaseCDinfo img').load(function() {
     setImgHeight('.releaseCDinfo img','div.releaseText');
});

$(window).resize(function(){
     setImgHeight('.releaseCDinfo img','div.releaseText');
});
```

Comment: Great, thanks. I thought that if I used the $(document).ready(), the function would not be called before the image was loaded. This solution works perfectly.

Comment: If you also ever find yourself doing something more complex, you can use this jQuery plugin which is very handy:  https://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded

Answer (score 0):

[.outerHeight()](http://api.jquery.com/outerheight/) returns a number in pixels without the "px" suffix, but the CSS [height](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/height) property requires the unit to be explicitly specified. So the right way to achieve what you want is:

```
$('div.releaseText').css('height', imgHeight + 'px');
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to wait for the DOM get ready in order to call your function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   setImgHeight();
});

$(window).resize(function(){
   setImgHeight();
});
```

If it is working after resizing, maybe it's a timing issue. try adding a timeout:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      setTimeout(setImgHeight, 100);
});
```

Comment: You don't need to wait for the DOM, you need to wait for the image to load.